# Dotnet/mono build is not reproducible

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, nuget

Working on a Mac (same problem on Linux)

```
$ rm -rf packages
$ git checkout upgrades-take2
$ dotnet clean
$ nuget restore Dggt.sln
$ msbuild
# Fails with one error
(CoreCompile target) -> Global.asax.cs(10,33): error CS0117: 'GlobalConfiguration' does not contain a definition for 'Configure' [./DggtApi/DggtApi.csproj]

9 Warning(s)
1 Error(s)

$ rm -rf packages
$ git checkout develop
$ dotnet clean
$ nuget restore Dggt.sln
$ msbuild
  # Success (3 warnings)
$ git checkout upgrades-take2
$ dotnet clean
$ nuget restore Dggt.sln
$ msbuild
# Success (14 warnings)
```

There are no changes to the code, just the `git` commands shown above and those packages just being present in the packages folder causes a different build to be produced.  Is .NET always this fragile?  How do we prevent this from happening?

Branch `develop` projects are on a mixture of .net452 -> .net472
Branch `upgrade-take2` projects are all on .net461

One of the dependent packages supports 4.6.1 and then jumps straight to .net5, that's why everything is standardized on 4.6.1

---

Trying `dotnet restore` just doesn't work

```
$ rm -rf packages/
$ dotnet restore Dggt.sln
Determining projects to restore...
Nothing to do. None of the projects specified contain packages to restore.
```

This project is not use PackageReferences because when I tried converting to that, all hell broke lose and it wasn't worth trying to fix it.  I just did a `git reset --hard` on that and that 1000s of build errors vanished.

I'm using `NuGet Version: 5.6.0.6489`

Comment: Are you using a recent version of nuget? Does it make a difference if you used `dotnet restore` instead of `nuget restore`?

Comment: I can't tell you what exactly is going on here, but still using packages.config might be part of the problem. Nuget (and particularly dotnet restore) work quite differently and much nicer when the new project format is being used. But yes, the first time you change that it's a bit of work. There might be tools to help you with the conversion, though.

Comment: Also, as you say you're using a Mac, I'm confused that your projects target .NET4.6.1, because ASFAIK that exists for Windows only. Or is there a version of mono involved?